# css bundle not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

Hy,

I have this in bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/WebStyle/css").Include(
                  "~/Styles/Master.css"
                  ));
```

this in layout page:

`@Styles.Render("~/WebStyle/css")`

this in css:

```
   #content #header .search .search_submit
{
    width:58px;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    border-left:1px solid #929394;
    color:#FFF;
    }
```

and this in html:

```
  <input type="button" class="search_submit" id="submit_button" value="Search" onclick="transfer()" />
```

But when I run my app, the button seems to be the same as before, style doesnt change. Whats wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by ~/WebStyle/css ? and where is located your css code ?

Comment: @MehdiSouregi I mean the name to apply to bundles to get css path. Nothing more. My css is located in APP/Styles

Comment: Using a modern browser, right-click the button and choose Inspect. In the Web Dev tools that apear, check what styles apply to it, and what elements/divs/classes/whatever the button is contained in. It should become clear then what is wrong. I tested your code and it works (if I add containing divs with ids/class as given + a form).

Comment: @PeterB where did you test my code? In simple example or in MVC, because I just tried and saw that if I leave only ".search_submit" it works. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I created a (temp) code snippet here on SO. If it works without the specifiers before `.search_submit` then those specifiers do not match the page structure. Either just leave them out as you did, or else you need to change the page to have the exact set of parent elements for the button to match what the css says.

Comment: @PeterB sorry , I cant get what you mean by "to have the exact set of parent elements for the button to match what the css says"